# Editing a Remedy User macro file.ARQ

Tags: remedy

Using BMC Remedy User v7.5 p004 to track/manage incidents. This tool has an option to record macros which are saved as a .ARQ file, I can open this file in Notepad++ but it is quite jumbled.

What I am trying to do is allow someone to search incidents based off of the summary that is put in the Working Log under the WorkInfo tab. I know that you can record macros that allow you to enter search variables that will prompt the end user, but when recording a macro the workinfo section is deactivated. So I would like to edit some pre-existing macros to try end create what I need.

SQL for what I want to pull

```
SELECT incidentno, summary, notes, summary*, notes*
FROM whatever the main table name is
WHERE WorkInfoType = WorkingLog
```

Note that the reason there are two summary and notes fields is because two of the fields are under the WorkingLog and the other two are fields listed for the whole incident. The BMC naming convention difference for these different fields is the *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this by recording a macro out of the advanced search form within the incident management console. Within that form you can select the fields you want to search and there is an advanced button that brings up a query box for more complicated searching. After changing WorkInfoType on the form to equal "Working Log" I used the following advanced query to finish off the rest of the search.

```
( 'Summary' LIKE "%$Search Technical Name$%") AND  ( 'Incident Status' = "Resolved" OR 'Incident Status' = "Closed" )  AND  ( 'Assigned Group' = "Group1" OR 'Assigned Group' = "Group2" )
```

Note: When recording a maco you can enter $VariableName$ to make a variable. This will allow a user to enter text in a search box for whatever field you make a variable. So for example in the query I made a variable called titled "Search Technical Name", and this prompts the user to search the summary field when running the macro. Also, the % act as a wildcard search which will hit on not exact matches.